# How to use JSON object to mysql query?

Tags: mysql, json, laravel

From a recent query I am getting this as the result.

```
[{"BeneficiaryID":"2"},{"BeneficiaryID":"3"},{"BeneficiaryID":"4"},{"BeneficiaryID":"6"}]
```

I want to use these ID values for another mysql query using Laravel.
 How can I just get only those numbers.
 Final result should be like `[2,3,4,6]`

Comment: So the data is stored as a json encoded string??

Comment: From mysql 5.7 you can use JSON data type https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html

Comment: Just the ID value take for another query, so has to remove BeneficiaryID part.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $data = json_decode('[{"BeneficiaryID":"2"},{"BeneficiaryID":"3"},{"BeneficiaryID":"4"},{"BeneficiaryID":"6"}]');

$id_array = [];

foreach($data as $data) {
    $id_array[] = $data->BeneficiaryID;
}

$query = Model::whereIn('column', $id_array)->get();
```

Comment: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: You're getting the result using toJson() method?

Comment: because in my answer a string is passed as parameter to json_decode function and the laravel toJson method is returning string as well? But if you don't need the json format you can use lists() method that will return an array

Comment: If we supply '[{"BeneficiaryID":"2"},{"BeneficiaryID":"3"},{"BeneficiaryID":"4"},{"BeneficiaryID":"6"}]', we are getting the correct output. but we are getting this as a variable, when its used 
 $data = json_decode($variable); we are getting errors.

Comment: that variable in JSON format. this is the result [{"BeneficiaryID":"2"},{"BeneficiaryID":"3"},{"BeneficiaryID":"4"},{"Beneficiar‌​yID":"6"}]